# Able to launch cmd file from python IDE, but not when launching the python script via a cmd file

Tags: python, kdb

I have a python script that starts by launching 2 KDB instances (2 cmd files launching KDB and setting up the ports).

I launch them using the subprocess module like this `subprocess.Popen([os.path.join(os.getcwd(),q.cmd)])`

Although it works like a charm when the script is ran from my IDE (spyder), I cannot see those two instances pop up when launching the python script from a cmd file (python.exe script.py).

the python used in the cmd file is the same as the one used in my spyder. The cmd launcher is in the same directory. I am not getting any error, I just don't see the instance popping up.

Comment: When you say the instances aren't popping up, do you mean that the kdb instances don't start up at all or that they don't start in a foreground window? Also it looks like you're using windows yes?

Comment: The instances weren't starting at all. Trying to connect to their port would fail. I ended up using shell=True and it worked.